# Assign Approval Process to Multiple Users from Apex

Tags: apex

I have a request to assign an approval process to two users. The users will not be known until run time based on relationships to the contact record. The ProcessSubmitRequest.setNextApproverIds() method shows a list of Ids as a param, but when I pass it a list with more than one value, I get an error that the next approver ID is missing. Is it possible to do this without a queue? I hope to avoid that solution because of the number of queues it would require to create and manage.

I did try to assign Ids with a loop. But that would fail because the record is now currently in an open approval process.

```
List<Id> ourIDs = new List<Id>{
        '0052J000009A04EQAS', '0052J000009eO7hQAE'
};


Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();


req1.setComments('Approval for you');
req1.setObjectId('003D500000ysrC4IAI');
req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
//req1.setNextApproverIds(ourIDs);//this fails with multiple IDs
req1.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{UserInfo.getUserId()});
req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('FooBar_Approval_Process');


Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
System.debug(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was assigning each request to a list of ProcessSubmitRequests.

And then passing that list to Approval.process()

```
List<Id> ourIDs = new List<Id>{
        '0052J000009A04EQAS', '0052J000009eO7hQAE'
};
List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> requests = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();
for(Id id: ourIDs) {
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('Approval for you');
    req1.setObjectId('003D500000ysrC4IAI');
    req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
    req1.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{id});

    req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Discover_Approval_Process');
    requests.add(req1);
}
List<Approval.ProcessResult> results = Approval.process(requests);
System.debug(results);
```

Answer (score -1):

List of Ids Iterate like

```
List<Id> ourIDs = new List<Id>{'0052J000009A04EQAS', '0052J000009eO7hQAE'};

for (Id recordId : ourIDs) 
{
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req1.setComments('Approval for you');
req1.setObjectId(recordId);
req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
req1.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{UserInfo.getUserId()});
req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('FooBar_Approval_Process');

Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
System.debug(result);
 }
```

> If the next step in your approval process is another Apex approval process, you specify exactly one user ID as the next approver. If not, you cannot specify a user ID and this method must be null.

Comment: This would attempt to put the same record into approval processes twice, would it not? Do you have a link to documentation that can corroborate what you're claiming here?

Comment: @DerekF [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ProcessRequest.htm#apex_Approval_ProcessRequest_setNextApproverIds)
i'm attached Official Docs

Comment: What I am trying to do is assign more than one user ID  to setNextApproveIds(). The method takes a list but seems to fail if you give it more than one value.

In this example I want to just assign the approval to everyone in the List OurIds.